# How can I use a variable from one Sub in another?

Tags: vb.net, variables, pong

Sorry that my English is bad. It´s not my native language.
Sorry for bad formatting in the code if there is some.

I'm pretty new to programming and I wanted to make a Pong game using vb.Net.
When the game starts, there are two buttons on the screen with that you can choose if you want to play alone or with another person.

When you click on one of the buttons, a boolean variable changes. I want to use this variable when I move the paddles. (One paddle can't be moved and gets moved automatically if you choose one player.) All variables get created globally. I hope you understand what my problem is. I couldn´t find any solutions that I could understand.

```
Public Sub Oneplayer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Oneplayer.Click
    oneplayer = True
End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If oneplayer = True Then
        player1Newpositive = player1.Location.Y + 1
        player1Newnegative = player1.Location.Y - 1

        If player1.Location.Y + 75 > ball.Location.Y Then
            player1.Location = New Point(player1.Location.X, player1Newnegative)
        ElsIf player1.Location.Y + 75 < ball.Location.Y Then
            player1.Location = New Point(player1.Location.X, player1Newpositive)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If it's a global variable, you should be able to use it in both the subs.

Comment: Declare it somewhere in the form as ```Private Property OnePlayer As Boolean``` (and use project settings ```Option Explicit On``` and ```Option Strict On```).

Answer (score 0):

For example, in `Form1` below, the variable `onePlayer` is declared at class level, and so it can be accessed by any `Sub`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private onePlayer As Boolean

    Public Sub Oneplayer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Oneplayer.Click
        oneplayer = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If onePlayer = True Then
            '...
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @Wüschli - Did this answer your question?